# Create a new column containing the concatenated unique elements of another in BigQuery SQL, using `string_agg`

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Given the following data:

```sql
WITH abc AS 
(
  SELECT 1234 id, 'Aug' month, 'P' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'Sept', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Sept', 'D' 
)
SELECT 
    month, 
    value, 
FROM abc
```

Which looks as:

[image]

I'd like to create a new column `values` which contains all values from the `value` columns.

So for this example data the new column would contain `P, D`.

Having done this the output would be (I've just written this out in Excel):

[image]

I tried to do this as follows:

```sql
WITH abc AS 
(
    SELECT 1234 id, 'Aug' month, 'P' value 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1234, 'Sept', 'P' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4567, 'Sept', 'D' 
)
SELECT 
    month, 
    value, 
    STRING_AGG(distinct value, " & ") as str_agg
FROM abc
```

But I get this error:

> SELECT list expression references column month which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [7:5]

I'm not sure how to aggregate/group the `value` column in order to satisfy this error.

Comment: show expected output

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Will add now

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
select * 
from abc, (
  select string_agg(distinct value, ', ') values
  from abc
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]